# Proving XOR, AND and constant True to be written as NAND

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I am extending off of a previous question
[NAND, XOR and AND](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2107663/nand-xor-and-and), and I am attempting to prove that using XOR, AND and constant True can be written to NAND.  This is because I was already able to prove NAND with **A∧B**, **A∨B** and **¬A**.

Below is the proposition that is equivalent to NAND and I am sadly stuck on where to go now.  I was thinking of expanding the last XOR but I feel that I can reduce the left side more before that?

> [{A V B} ⊕ {A ⊕ T}] ⊕ A

[image: Here is the work I have done so far,]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression uses an $\lor$, so that is definitely not good, since you need to use only $\land$, $\oplus$, and $\top$.

Here is something you can do: since $A$ NAND $B \Leftrightarrow \neg (A \land B)$, and since $P \oplus \top \Leftrightarrow \neg P$, you have that $A$ NAND $B \Leftrightarrow (A\land B) \oplus \top$.

Comment: That was suppose to be a AND, so it was a typo, thanks for pointing that out